# PowerShell Variable into SMTP email

Tags: powershell-3.0

I'd like to run the following for loop which works. Load it into a variable and send the results to an SMTP server. Any ideas on how to do it. Google isnt getting me anywhere.

```
$Servers = get-content C:\Server\server.txt

$To = "test@test.com"
$From = "test@test.com"
$SMTPserver = "mail.mail.com" 
$Subject="Server Status" 

$message = foreach($server in $servers) 
{
Get-WmiObject win32_processor -computername $server | select SystemName, 
LoadPercentage
} 

$smtp=new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer) 
$smtp.Send($From, $To, $Subject, $Message)
```

Comment: "which works" So, if it works already, what are you asking for? What does it not do that you want it to do? This is an unclear question.

Comment: The $message isnt outputted as a string in the SMTP.Send its blank. So its not picking up the contents of the for loop as a string for the smtp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SmtpClient expects a message of type string however, if you run your query with the following `Write-Host` you are going to notice that `$message` is not of type string:

```
$message = foreach($server in $servers) 
{
    Get-WmiObject win32_processor -computername $server | select SystemName, 
    LoadPercentage
} 

Write-Host ("Message is of type " + ($message.GetType()))
```

You can simply format message using e.g. `Out-String` to get a string like this:

```
Write-Host ("Message " + ($message | Out-String))
```

you can define it inline if you like or store the string message in a variable first:

```
$smtp.Send($From, $To, $Subject, ($Message | Out-String) )
```